# Example of good project structure for large Android projects

Tags: android, class, directory-structure, code-organization

Working with a few people on an Android project that is growing to be quite large. We'd like to make sure that the organization is as good as can be. So I was just looking for what guidelines and patterns people are using for structuring their large android projects in regards to packages, classes and accessing methods between classes. The best thing would of course be a github link to a project you think is particularly good!

Our project is an application web centered using webviews with the accompanying native UI elements.

Comment: This question is alas outside the scope of Stackoverflow. A quick answer would be to say that it really depends on what kind of project it is. Games and web-based applications will certainly have much different organizations. There is no "one true" pattern, but just think as if you had to discover your own project with completely foreign eyes, and what you would want to see to understand it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html might help a bit

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a very high level example.

But I usually have packages for fragment types, data, services, dialogs, adapters, controls etc. This makes it much easier to locate files in a huge project.

I use an entirely flexible fragment system that only ever uses one activity, it's much easier to pass data this way.